# Live datasets in Carto using Census API

Tags: carto, api, census

I want to get population counts for places in California. [Ideally Census Tracts, but that's not a supported geography in the population dataset?]

After reading through the documentation and requesting an API Key I built this URL:

```
    https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1?get=B01001_001E,NAME&for=place:*&in=state:06&key=<api_key_goes_here>
```

I get the expected response in JSON format when I type it into a web browser but when I go connect the dataset in Carto, I get an error about supported files. Is the URL formatted properly? Am I connecting it incorrectly? I've been using the "connect dataset" and pasting the URL there.

Answer (score 1):

[As explained in the docs](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/import-api/importing-geospatial-data/), CARTO does not support JSON files. The URL should point to a supported format such as csv, shp or geojson.